# Is it possible to get info about my friends's friend using OpenSocial?

Tags: social-networking, opensocial

I know you cant do that with the Facebook API. Does OpenSocial allow me to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible. Another case in example is Twitter API